# How to configure two column layouts on a subflow?

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I've setup account creation through flow and to be more specific there is first a set of choices given to user to select from (main flow) and then based on the selection specific subflows are called.

Now, one of the the subflow have a screen with a lot of fields that all come on a single column so it would be nice to have them rearranged on two columns . I know there is a way we can enable two column layout when we call the flow from a custom button (by modifying the URL and adding a parameter for two column layout) but in this case the flow is a subflow which is called from a main flow which is started from a lightning component overriding the standard NEW button.

Is there any way I can configure the subflow screen to have a two column layout ?

-Thanks.

Comment: Don't think this is possible. `The layout setting is applied at the flow level. So you can’t control the layout at the screen or field level.` https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_design_layout.htm

Comment: Thanks Prakhar ! If this isn’t possible out of the box then I guess the only solution would be to implement a custom component and then use it in on the screen instead of the oob elements.

Comment: [Winter '21](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_multicolumn_screens.htm) will be releasing this ability as a pilot.

Answer (score 0):

In the current release (Winter'22) this is possible, by using sections. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_screencmp_section.htm&type=5) is the appropriate Salesforce documentation for that.